# Group concat sum of monthly sales for every customer based on regions

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, 1. customers that has customer address (JSON data) and 2. orders that has customer order amount (JSON data).

I want to join both the tables and get the below data:

[image]

But, I am getting the below data:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
SELECT json_extract(address, '$.locality') AS llocality, ttlprice, consumer_id 
    from (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(a.totprice) as ttlprice, consumer_id FROM (SELECT SUM(json_extract(amount, '$.sub_amount')) as totprice, consumer_id FROM orders GROUP BY MONTH(created_date), consumer_id) a GROUP by a.consumer_id) v
join consumer o
group by llocality, consumer_id
```

Comment: Provide a fiddle with desired output for it.

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iWwhCZomRbibjBJr3qc9VU/3 @Akina

Comment: No one is interested?

Answer (score 0):

Following adding your fiddle, the required SQL is as follows:

```
Select json_extract(consumer.address, '$.locality') AS locality,        GROUP_CONCAT(a.monthTotal), a.consumer_id                                    From (SELECT consumer_id, SUM(json_extract(amount, '$.sub_amount')) as monthTotal from `orders` GROUP BY MONTH(created_date), consumer_id) a Join `consumer` ON a.consumer_id=consumer.id GROUP BY a.consumer_id, consumer.address
```

It did take me a while to get my head around what you needed; I managed to break it down by chunking it down into smaller SQL problems, then tie it together at the end.

I have attached your fiddle updated with my workings; you should find the final statement covers everything you need.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iWwhCZomRbibjBJr3qc9VU/4

Comment: I did add DISTINCT earlier but it didnot work; thus, removed. Will try to provide a fiddle.

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iWwhCZomRbibjBJr3qc9VU/3